# How to find the HTTP Post URL and parameters of a website to parse in Android

Tags: android, html, http, post

I am trying to interface multiple accounts into a single one. I mean, consider you sell your own stuff at Sites A, B, C, D. I am trying to develop an app, such that the user has to enter his credentials in the settings screen, and from then on, the app automatically logs into each of the site, and parse the HTML to get the balance.
The issue here is, I don't find any API for any of the sites. So Can i open the source of the Login page, and use it to find the HTTP Post URL and the username and password field name tags and use it as normal post? Will it login? Have you ever tried such thing.

You help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Nithin

Comment: It depends. Most eCommerce sites have ways to restrict sending from third party logins(such as using a temporary key that's generated each time, user headers, etc).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [Firebug in Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/) or (Tools->Developer Tools in CHrome) to find out what is sent as POST parameters & then simulate the same in java.

I wrote a simple script to send SMS using a website and wrote on howto simulate logins. You can have a look at it [here.](http://linux-junky.blogspot.com/2010/03/python-script-for-sending-free-sms-in.html) It uses python but gives an idea of how is it done.

Comment: That was awesome! I'm trying it in Chrome now. Is Firebug any better btw? Also, after login, it navigates me to a different page. So in Android (Java), will the cookies be stored in the same place? Or how do i redirect. Any comments please?

Comment: No, you can use anyone. You handle cookies using a cookiejar. So, you just have to keep that cookiejar same while making the requests.